# how to store mobile number in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to store the 10 digit mobile number in int, but it is saying that its out of range, how can i store in int, any help pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [a proper TelephoneNumber type class](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/registry/infomodel/TelephoneNumber.html):

```
public interface TelephoneNumber
A simple re-usable entity class that defines attributes of a telephone number.
```

Comment: Because it's part of the XML package and that's not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 17):

There is no semantic value in storing it as a number - you won't be doing any numerical operations on it. You should store the value as a string.

Answer (score 16):

A mobile number might start with a 0 (zero) therefore I wouldn't advice to store it as a number. My advice would be to store it as a String. Otherwise you should use a long.

Comment: Good point! Plus, phone numbers can be up to 19 digits long, not including extensions, so a String is definitely in order (also for the country code which is sometimes prefixed by `+`)

Comment: Plus, a phone number can be represented as letters too, i.e. `1-555-THE-DUDE`

Answer (score 3):

You'd better use String, but you can also use long or BigInteger.
But using String will allow you to store dashes or spaces between numbers.

Comment: A float won't do the job as it can only store 7 significant digits.

Comment: A phone number is not a number that you want to do arithmetical operations on. It's really nothing more than a kind of label. Don't use a type that's meant for arithmetical manipulations, such as `int` or `BigInteger`. Just use a string.

Comment: BigInteger is no good.  You'll lose the leading zero, if it has one.

Answer (score 3):

Mobile numbers uses and [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) numbering format for telephone or digital communications. You will have to use Strings as valid characters such as "+"/"-" can be found in mobile numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at Java's BigInteger? Two possible references are:

- [Oracle BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)
- [Java Notes BigInteger](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/numbers/10biginteger.html)

Comment: If its not stored with a leading 0 (zero) then this might work better,
otherwise I would also say a string would do. Sometimes a mobile number would be stored with the country code in front i.e. 27831234567

Answer (score 2):

Use a String, for for proper semantics I would wrap it in your own MobileNumber class.

Answer (score 1):

use `Long` or `String` instead of `Integer`. Or give us some code examples for what you are trying to do.